# how to improve fonts in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am doing some development in Chrome/IE 11 and the style for an header in a table for IE it is look strange.
The style what I am using is the next for both:

```
{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: 100;
    background-color: rgb(222, 147, 83);
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

[image: Differences between Chrome and IE 11]

I tried change  font-weight property with no luck.

Comment: It looks like there may be some sort of `text-shadow` going on. Do you have an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Anthony. text-shadow was the problem. Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there may be some sort of `text-shadow` going on. Add `text-shadow: none;` to your css selector.